# Pass different controller scope to $uibModal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am inside Test A `controller`, from where I am loading the `TestB.html` whose controller is `TestB`.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'TestB.html',
    controller: 'ModalController',
    scope: $scope
});
```

How can I pass `TestB`'s scope to `$uibModal` instead of current scope. I kinda tried below, but not working.

```
var TestBscope = $controller('TestBController', {$scope: $scope});

var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'TestB.html',
    controller: 'ModalController',
    scope: TestBscope
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a different scope? If your goal is to share data between the two controllers then the answer is to use a service instead.

Comment: resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.passData;
    }
  }       and ModalInstance ctrl $scope.items = items;

Comment: Try like this .. http://embed.plnkr.co/rTN7Hj/